# How to store file to Weblogic context root?

Tags: weblogic

I'm a complete newbie to Weblogic, HTML and webpages in general, learning as I go. So I'm hoping my question is understandable.

I have a JSP page deployed in Weblogic that displays an image of a user. I will be getting the raw data of the JPG image from a database and writing it to a .jpg file locally on the server.

Originally, I wrote it to a local directory on the server like `/test/image/foo.jpg`. However, I believe `<IMG src='/test/image/foo.jpg' width="120" height="134" border="0">` does not work. So I'm guessing that I have to store this file in the "context root" for it to be accessible.

How do I do this?

Other information:

My webapp is packaged in a ear file named `mywebapp.ear`. If I store images beforehand in the war file I'm able to access them with `IMG src='/mywebapp/<imagename>.jpg`. However, Weblogic does not "explode" war files, so there is no way to write to the "root directory" of my deployed webapp right?

SOLUTION:
Virtual Directory Mappings was the answer.

Here's my weblogic.xml for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

<virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>/test</local-path>
        <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Note that it doesn't work if /test/image is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weblogic allows you to define a `virtual-directory-mapping` so that any path on the file system can be mapped to a URL of your choice

See more at

http://weblogicserveradministration.blogspot.in/2010/10/virtual-directory-mapping-in-webapps.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039396

So if you save your images to whatever path, you can access this as `/test/image/foo.jpg` provided you define the

`<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>` within the `virtual-directory-mapping` in weblogic.xml

Comment: Thanks Josek! I added my weblogic.xml for reference for future readers.